# cloud shell refers to an incorrect organization ID

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, cloud, google-cloud-shell

I am able to create a new project with the same user account, but I cannot seem to do this from cloud shell.

I get the following error:

```
failed: 7: Permission 'resourcemanager.projects.create' denied on parent resource 'organizations/{someId}'.
```

The problem is I have no idea what this someId is. It definitely does not refer the the orgID my project (from which I am running this) is a child of.

I tried to see if it's something in my environment variables, but don't see anything. Is this a known bug?

Comment: I'm not aware of that but you can set the organization ID in the command line https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/create#--organization

Comment: @chickenman, have u managed to check my below comment.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to replicate the same in my cloud shell and faced the same error. And I tried with different versions as well but still the same output. As you mentioned, it seems like a bug. Feel free to either raise a [Public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)  or contact [google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) for the same issue .

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I did enable that role. If it were not enabled, I would not have been able to create projects from the UI. The "someID"  is just an attempt to mask the actual Id for security.

Comment: I apologize for misunderstanding the issue. As I can’t see that you mentioned that you enabled the role. And you mentioned that:

>The problem is I have no idea what this someId is. It definitely does not refer to the orgID my project (from which I am running this) is a child of.

Comment: Hence I shared my previous answer accordingly. I have updated my answer now. Please have a look at it now.

Comment: how did you replicate the issue?

Comment: I have replicated the issue by trying to create a new project from cloud shell by using the command `gcloud projects create example-foo-bar-789 --name="Happy project" --labels=type=happy`.